# How should a C++ function to calculate nearest distance to point be written?

Tags: c++, function, object-oriented-analysis

I posted this question yesterday but it was my first post so my question wasn't really clear.
I have a homework, the output is below the code. I'm stuck at creating a function that calculates the nearest distance.
The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct obstacle {
    string carname;
    float x, y;
    float distance;
    obstacle *next;
};
obstacle *head = nullptr;

float DistanceToOrigin (float x, float y)
{
    float distance;
    distance = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y));
    return distance;
}
float CalcNearestPoint(obstacle points[], obstacle point, int n)
{
    obstacle temp;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(points[i].distance>points[i-1].distance)
        {
            temp.distance = points[i].distance;
            points[i].distance = points[i-1].distance ;
            points[i-1].distance = temp.distance;
        }
    }
    DistanceToOrigin(points[0].x,points[0].y);

}
void insertObstacle (string name, float a, float b)
{
    obstacle *newObstacle = new obstacle;
    newObstacle->carname = name;
    newObstacle->x = a;
    newObstacle->y = b;
    newObstacle->next = head;
    head = newObstacle;
}
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    string name;
    while (name != "0"){

        {
        cout << "string describing obstacle (""0"" for end of input):";
        cin >>name;
        cout << "\nx and y coordinate: ";
        cin >> x >> y;
        insertObstacle(name, x, y);
        }

    }
}
```

And the task is:

> Write a function that returns a pointer to the closest obstacle / closest point for a list of obstacles / points as the first parameter and an obstacle / point as the second parameter. Note that an obstacle / point is not returned to itself (distance 0), and that there must be at least two obstacles / points, otherwise the zero pointer should be returned nullptr. /

```
And the required output:
string describing obstacle ("end" for end of input): A 
x and y coordinate: 0 1 
string describing obstacle ("end" for end of input): X 
x and y coordinate: 1 1 
string describing obstacle ("end" for end of input): E 
x and y coordinate: 0 3 
string describing obstacle ("end" for end of input): K 
x and y coordinate: -1 4 
string describing obstacle ("end" for end of input): W 
x and y coordinate: 0 10 
obstacle obstacle (end of end): end 
obstacle A: (0.00, 1.00), distance: 1.00m, nearest to this: X 
obstacle X: (1.00, 1.00), distance: 1.41m, nearest to this: A 
obstacle E: (0.00, 3.00), distance: 3.00m, nearest to this: K
obstacle K: (-1.00, 4.00), distance: 4.12m, nearest to this: E 
obstacle W: (0.00, 10.00), distance: 10.00m, nearest to this: K 
delete: AX
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you've shown here it looks like your trying to create a link list and are being asked to find within the linked list the obstacle that is the shortest distance away in which your current code (within your insert obstacle) never links the obstacles into a list, it just links the next object to the head, the other obstacles being lost as nothing points to them anymore, thus your never have a list to look over. You may want to read up on [linked lists.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-vs-array/)

Next your CalcNearstPoint function is based upon the assumption that your working with an array however as I said before it looks like your trying to use a linked list in which case you need to modify it to step through the linked list with a while loop that checks that the next pointer is not null like this

```
obstacle *temp = head;
while(temp->next != nullptr)
{
    ...
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

So to summarise you first need to fix your insertOstacle function then you need to write your CalcNearstPoint to be able to step through the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

**key ponts:**

1. Your `CalcNearstPoint` function accepts argument for an `array` instead of a `linked_list` (*as pointed out by* @That_Linux_Guy)
2. The second argument `point` of your function `CalcNearstPoint` was never used. Perhaps you are trying to calculate the obstacle in a set obstacles `points` with shortest distance to `point`.

```
bool is_zero(double d)
{
  static const double epsilon = 1e-6;
  return ((d >= -epsilon) && (d <= epsilon));
}

double distance(obstacle *A, obstacle *B)
{
  double x = (B->x - A->x);
  double y = (B->y - A->y);
  return std::sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
}

obstacle* CalcNearestPoint(linked_list<obstacle> &points, obstacle *point)
{
  obstacle ptr = points.BEGIN, *tmp = nullptr;
  double d0;

  for (; (ptr != nullptr); ptr = ptr->next)
  {
    double d = distance(ptr, point);
    if ((tmp == nullptr) || (d < d0))
    {
      d0 = d; tmp = ptr;
    }
  }

  return (((tmp != nullptr) && (is_zero(d0) == false)) ? tmp : nullptr);
}
```

> if d0 is zero, then `point` is defined in set of obstacles `points`

3. You should also readup on `linked-list` here is a simple implementation

```
template<typename T> struct linked_list
{
  T *BEGIN;
  linked_list(void) : BEGIN(nullptr) {}
  linked_list(const linked_list<T>&) = delete;
 ~linked_list(void) { clear(); }

  void clear(void)
  {
    //....
  }
};
```